# number characters from input

Tags: c, arrays, loops, duplicates, char

```
bool in_array(char a[], char input, int len){
  for (int l = 0; l < len; l++){

    }
  }
  return false;
}


int main(void) {


  char i = 'l';
  int count = 0;
  int count_d = 0;
  char a[1000] = {0};

    else{
      count_d++;
    }
  }
  printf("%d\n", count_d);

}
```

this is the code i have but this returns numbers of times it has duplicated

as there are two characters a and b

Comment: how would you solve this without malloc or going into dynamic memory

Comment: To counter your comment/question: How would you solve this *with* dynamic memory allocation? If you find an answer to that question, how would you remove dynamic memory allocation from your solution?

Comment: @EOF i havent learned dynamic memory location , so i don't know , I'm still a beginner

Comment: @mkrieger1: The array does not contain the numbers of times characters were seen. It contains a list of characters that were seen.

Comment: @mkrieger1 That doesn't scale well to larger alphabets.

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes thats why i am confused at what i should do

Comment: Actually I don’t understand what the code is doing. It should be quite simple. I guess you take a step back and think about how you would do this on paper.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Don't feel bad, it's misleading. Remember rule 1: comments always lie.

Comment: In order to know how many different characters were repeated, you need to know how many characters were seen more than once. For each character, in order to know whether it has been seen more than once, you need to know whether it has been seen zero, one, or more than one times. Figure out how to track that information for each character. Also, do not assume ASCII is in use or that there are 128 characters. The number of possible `unsigned char` values is `UCHAR_MAX+1`, where `UCHAR_MAX` is defined in `<limits.h>`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Actually, It is difficult to win all the people. I tried to deviate as minimal as possible from the OP code. I don't know what more you want me to explain!? It is just one ``while`` loop, one ``for`` loop and one ``printf``. Most of them were already created by OP, and moreover I commented at a few places where it is necessary. Yes, It should be ``256`` (in general) or maybe something else, which I might not be aware of. I don't have a vast experience like you, Sir. With the reputation as high as yours, it won't even take a min to change it from ``255`` to ``256``. Thank You.

Comment: @MohithReddy: For one thing, your code completely changed the meaning of the `a` array. In the original code, the elements of the `a` array were a list of characters see; `a[count]` was the code for the <i>n</i>-th unique character seen, where `count` was *n*. In your code, the elements were counts of how many times each character was seen; `a[i]` was the number of times the character with code `i` was seen.

Comment: @MohithReddy: As for explaining, the above shows part of how you do it; you write sentences that say what things are: “The meaning of `a[i]` is that `a[i]` is the number of times the character with code `i` was seen.” You state what variables are used for, and you write sentences explaining what the code is doing with them. For example; “`a[i] = a[i] + 1;` increments the element for the character with code `i` to keep a count of how many times it is seen.” And “We can use the count to know whether a character was seen more than once.”

Answer (score 0):

If you have learnt only arrays and do not know how to allocate memory dynamically then use a second array to store unique duplicated characters.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool in_array( const char a[], size_t n, char c )
{
    size_t i = 0;
    
    while ( i != n && a[i] != c ) i++;
    
    return i != n;
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 128 };
    char a[N];
    char b[N / 2];
    
    size_t count_duplicates = 0;
    size_t count = 0;
    
    char c;
    
    while ( count < N && scanf( " %c", &c ) == 1 )
    {
        if ( !in_array( a, count, c ) )
        {
            a[count++] = c;
        }
        else if ( !in_array( b, count_duplicates, c ) )
        {
            b[count_duplicates++] = c;
        }
    }
    
    printf( "There are %zu duplicated character(s).\n", count_duplicates );
    
    return 0;
}
```

If to enter the sequence of characters

```
aaabbaaac
```

then the program output will be

```
There are 2 duplicated character(s).
```

Answer (score -2):

i hope it will help you :

```
`#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int in_a(char *a, char c)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++)
        if (a[i] == c)
            return 0;
    return (1);
}

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    int count_duplicates = 0;
    int same = 0; 
    char old = 0;
    char new[128] = {0}; // i
    int count = 0;
    char *a = av[1];
    while (a[count] != '\0') {
        if (old != a[count] && in_a(new, a[count])) {
            same = 0;
        }
        if (a[count] == old && same != 1) {
            count_duplicates += 1;
            same = 1;
        }
        old = a[count];
        new[count] = a[count];
        count += 1;
    }
    printf("%i\n", count_duplicates);
    return (0);
}`
```